# My code doesn't work for more then 2 digits numbers and and negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, this is my task. Extract numbers from a text file and then calculate the sum of them.
I wrote the code successfully and but it doesn't work fine with 2 or more digit numbers and negative numbers. What should i do?

```
f = open('file6.txt', 'r')
suma = 0
file = f.readlines()
for line in file:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
             suma += int(i)
print("The sum is ", suma)
```

file6.txt:

```
1
10
```

Output:

```
The sum is  2
```

Comment: What do you think `for i in line` does?

Comment: if you print i you will see the loop goes like 1 1 0

Comment: i would just remove the inner for loop, jus have it like `if line.isdigit(): ...`

Comment: You have too many for-loop. Try this: `print("The sum is ", sum([int(line) for line in f.readlines()]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are going line by line first through the loop and looking at every digit ( in second loop ) to add.
And /n at the end of elements make the .isDigit() function disabled to find the digits.
So your updated code should be like this :

```
f = open('file6.txt', 'r')
suma = 0
file = f.readlines()
for line in file:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        suma += int(line)
print("The sum is ", suma)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split the input into words on anything that is not part of a number. Try to convert the words into numbers, silently skip if this fails.

```
import re

sum_nums_in_file = 0

with open('file6.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in re.split(r'[^-+\dEe.]+', line):
            try:
                num = float(word)
                sum_nums_in_file += num
            except:
                pass

print(f"The sum is {sum_nums_in_file}")
```

This works for example on files such as this:

```
-1 2.0e0
+3.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use re module in this task. But thank you so much for helping though